# Javascript array updating field, setting value for every item in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an update form that supposed to take price in an input field and update it into an array with the id as the unique id. Having issue with it that it's updating the last price overrides the previous set price.

```
<input placeholder="None" class="price" id="114157">
<input placeholder="None" class="price" id="114158">
<input placeholder="None" class="price" id="114159">
```

The Javascript

```
var objects = {};

 var array_list = {'price':false, 'tue_price':false, 'view': false, 'cinema': false, 'id': false, 'kids_price': false, 'free_seating': false, 'vip_consetions': false};
 $( ".price" ).change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (objects[id]) {
        objects[id]['price'] = $(this).val();
    }else{
        objects[id] = array_list;
        objects[id]['price'] = $(this).val();
        objects[id]['id'] = $('.price[id='+id+']').val();
    }
    console.log(objects);
});
```

I've setup an example fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/natcdgkq/

Comment: Because it's always pointing to the same object reference. So `objects[id]` will always be pointing at the same object.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli actually in the fiddle i have different input field with different ids

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I've updated the question it creates new `array_list` put the price for the new and all old ones are set to the same number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you only have a single copy of the `array_list` (poor name) object. So each time you assign it and change the value, it's always the same object reference. You could do what is essentially a copy:

```
var objects = {};

var array_list = {
    'price': false,
    'tue_price': false,
    'view': false,
    'cinema': false,
    'id': false,
    'kids_price': false,
    'free_seating': false,
    'vip_consetions': false
};

$(".price").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'),
        o = objects[id];
    if (!o) {
        objects[id] = o = jQuery.extend({}, array_list);
    }
    o.price = $(this).val();
});
```

I omitted the portion about the id, that doesn't really make a lot of sense. You already have the object you're trying to query for.